# Merge concept in Oracle

Tags: oracle

```
**Before Merge:**
***Source table as SRC***                      
-------------
| A | B | C |
-------------
| a | b | 10|
| c | d | 20|
| w | x | 30|
| w | y | 40|
| w | z | 50|
------------- 

***Target Table as TGT***
--------------
| D | E | F   |
--------------
| a | b | null|
| c | e | null|
| w | m | null|
| w | n | null|
| w | o | null|
-------------

***After Merge:***
***Target table as TGT***
 -----------
| D | E | F |
------------
| a | b | 10|
| c | e | 20|
| w | m | 50|
 -----------
```

I have mentioned 2 tables above: one as source table and other as target table

I want to merge above two tables and store result in target in oracle

**Logic:**
**1st logic:** (find out the matching values of A and to D and B column to E column and ***only 1 match found***)
Ex: A.a = D.a and B.b = E.b then update C column value to F column i.e. F=10

**2nd logic:** If 1st logic not found then find out the matching values of A column to the D column and B column value don’t match with E column and ***only 1 match found***)
Ex: A.c = D.c then update C column value to F column i.e. F=20

**3rd logic:**  If 1st logic and 2nd logic not found then find out the matching values of A column to the D column and B column value don’t match with E column and ***multiple matches found***) then update the C column value of highest number in F column.
Ex: A.w = D.w -> we have 3 rows, out of those we select the value  which has high value i.e. 50 and store this value in F column i.e. F = 50 in one row and remove other two rows

After merging, no. of rows are reduced. How to write a program for this using MERGE concept in oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the corelated sub-query as follows:

```
Update tgt t
   Set t.f = (Select Coalesce(Max(case when s.b = t.e then s.c end), Max(s.c))
From src s
Where s.a = t.d)
```

Comment: If you have enough time, would you explain it briefly as I am new to merge concept and the three logics?

Comment: I have taken all rows from src table which has match for d in target and created two expressions. First will take care of logic 1. Second will take care of logic 2 and 3. And both of them are in coalesce which will utltimately provide you desired result. Max is used to satisfy the logic 3.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue then you should accept the answer so that it is marked as resolved.

Comment: If there are 100's of records, by running the above query, do we get expected result?

Comment: MERGE INTO TGT T
USING SRC S
ON ((S.A = T.D) AND (S.B = T.E))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET T.F = S.C
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN..............Do I need to add above UPDATE query in this after NOT MATCHED THEN part?

Comment: When I removed WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN part, 1st logic part is getting merged successfully but I have doubt on 2nd and 3rd logic part like how should I write logic of 2nd and 3rd logic part in WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN clause part?

Comment: In Not matched part, You can use INSERT query

Comment: Can you post the continuation of my code please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually I need to update F column right not insert right

Comment: Why you want merge? You can use the Update as per my answer.

Comment: perfect Popeye...Above ans is working fine...Thank You

Comment: If we have million records, merge concept will work faster than update right? Am I correct about this?

Comment: May be or may not be. depends on Indexes and this is the best solution that I can see for your requirement.